# CSS padding issues in IE and Chrome

Tags: css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, padding

Please check out the following
http://healthfacilitiesgroup.com/pm/phaseinfo.php
in IE and in Chrome.
I want the site to be 8.5in wide with 1in "margin" on either side (meaning 6.5in wide paragraphs etc.). I thought the way to do this was a div that was 8.5in wide and 1in padding. That's how the CSS is set up but for some reason IE and Chrome handle this totally differently. I'm less than novice to html, so thanks for anything.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a doctype, so your site is rendering in [Quirks Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode). Quirks Mode + IE = hopeless.

You can escape Quirks Mode and achieve consistency simply by adding this as the very first line:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

That's the HTML5 doctype, and it will trigger Standards Mode.

Comment: And never, ever use IE as a reference for how things should work. Always, always use *any* other browser to help verify your markup. Then look to see how IE screws everything up. But the multitude of problems with IE are well known, as are the hacks to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Because screen resolutions differ, it is difficult to get the same amount (1 inch) of margin on either side of your centered design.

Instead of designing in inches, it is better for you to design in percentages.  This will give you a more consistent look that will expand or contract depending on the screen resolution of the user.

For instance, you might consider setting your main `div` to `80%` and then giving it an automatic `margin`, which would fill up the other space.  Something like...

`div#main{width:80%, margin:0 auto;}`

The first figure `0` sets the `margin` from the top and bottom and the `auto` configures it to match the sides.

`Padding`, by the way, deals with space inside the element.  See more here: http://www.goer.org/HTML/intermediate/margins_and_padding/